# Invoke button in a game / external program C#

Tags: c#, button, directx, invoke

Is it possible to invoke a click on a specific button in a game / external program without having the mouse over the button?

I have tried searching but found nothing on this topic.

Comment: Whatever you want, first decide for a language. And is this your game (ie. you have the code) or an external program?

Comment: external program and  prefer to code it in c#

Answer (score 0):

You can send message to your program from outside of application.

For example, if you are using Win32 application as external application, then you can use `FindWindow`, `SendMessage` api to send message and click the button.

Please be specific on language so will get exact answers.

Comment: He wants to invoke a button from a separate programme. I.e. Simulate a mouse click without actually clicking the mouse.